# Фильтр по диапозону цены

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть такой небольшой фильтр:

```js
var filterAll = $('.filter-all'),
    boxs = $('.box'),
    length = boxs.length;
filterAll.text(length);

// Checkbox
$('input:checkbox').on('change', function() { 
  
   var 
     filter = new RegExp($(":checkbox:checked")
                         .map(function() {
                           return this.value;
                         })
                         .get()
                         .join("|") );

  //console.log(filter);
  
  $(".box").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this[filter.source != "" && filter.test($this.attr("class")) ? "show" : "hide"]();
        
  });        
});

// Range Slider
var range = document.getElementById('range'),
    t = [],
    maximum = parseInt(range.attributes.max.value, 10),
    minimum = parseInt(range.attributes.min.value, 10),
    delta = (maximum - minimum) / 4,
    options = {
      min: [minimum],
      "25%": [minimum + delta * 1, 1e6],
      "50%": [minimum + delta * 2, 1e6],
      "75%": [minimum + delta * 3, 1e6],
      max: [maximum]
    };

//console.log(minimum + delta * 1, 1e6);

t.push(parseInt(range.attributes.min.value, 10)), 
  t.push(parseInt(range.attributes.max.value, 10));
var n = parseInt(range.attributes.max.value, 10); 
// i = parseInt(range.attributes.min.value, 10),

noUiSlider.create(
  range, 
  {
    range: options,
    start: t,
    connect: !0,
    pips: {
      mode: "range",
      density: 2
    }
  }
);

$(".noUi-value-horizontal").each(function() {
  var range = $(this).text().split("").slice(0, -6).join("");
  $(this).html(range);
});


range.noUiSlider.on('change', function(values, handle){
  $(".box").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
        price = $this.data('price');
    
    var val1 =  values[0];
    var val2 =  values[1];
    
    if(price <= val2 && price >= val1 ) {
      $this.show();
    }else {
      $this.hide();
    }
    
  });
});


//   var filterSelect = $('.filter-select'),
//     boxs = $('.box'),
//     length = boxs.length;
//     filterSelect.text(length);
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
} */

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.filter-item {
    border: 4px solid #ccc;
    margin: .1rem;
    padding: .5rem .95rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label,
.filter-item.active, 
.filter-item:hover, 
.filter-item:not(.active):hover {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}

.slider-wrapper {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.filter-res {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.filter-res span {
  color: red;
}

.box {
  width: 8rem;
  height: 8rem;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 3rem 0;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/10.1.0/nouislider.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/10.1.0/nouislider.min.js"></script>
  
  
<div class="filter">
  Кол-во комнат
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="item">
      <input type="checkbox" id="room-1" value="room-1">
      <label for="room-1" class="filter-item" >
        1        
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <input type="checkbox" id="room-2" value="room-2">
      <label for="room-2" class="filter-item" >
        2        
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <input type="checkbox" id="room-3" value="room-3">
      <label for="room-3" class="filter-item" >
        3        
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <br>
  
  Метраж
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="item">      
      <input type="checkbox" id="area-1" value="area-1">
      <label for="area-1" class="filter-item" >
        50-100        
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <input type="checkbox" id="area-2" value="area-2">
      <label for="area-2" class="filter-item" >
        100-200        
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
  <br>
  
  Цена
  <div class="slider-wrapper">
    <div id="range" max="28420000" min="6130000"></div>
  </div>
  
  <br>
  <div class="filter-res">
    Выбрано <span class="filter-slect">0</span> из <span class="filter-all">0</span> 
  </div>
  
</div>
  
  <div class="content">
    <div class="box room-1 area-1" data-price="6140000">
      room="1" <br> area="70" <br> 6 140 000
    </div>
    
    <div class="box room-2 area-2" data-price="17000000">
      room="2" <br> area="70" <br> 17 000 000
    </div>
    
    <div class="box room-3 area-3" data-price="27000000">
      room="3" <br> area="70" <br> 27 000 000
    </div>
  </div>
```

Range Slider - [noUiSlider](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/)

По чекбоксам работает все, но вот со слайдером загвоздка.

Смысл в том, что при перемещении ползунка, только попавшие в диапозон цены товары отображались (с учетом чекбоксов) и результат фильтра (количество отображенных товаров) записывались в `.filter-select`.

Сейчас, выбираю диапозон цены, потом выбираю кол-во комнат (чекбокс) - все работает, потом убираю выбор комнаты (снимаю чекбокс) и все сбрасывается.

**Вопрос:** Как реализовать фильтр товаров по range слайдеру с учетом чекбоксов и записать количество всех выведенных результатов?

Comment: Вам нужно сначала собрать все данные а потом проверять их при событиях

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если правильно понял то что то типо того?

```js
var filterAll = $('.filter-all'),
    boxs = $('.box'),
    length = boxs.length;
filterAll.text(length);  
var count_box;

var filter =   filter = new RegExp($(":checkbox:checked")
                         .map(function() {
                           return this.value;
                         }).get().join("|") );
                         
$('input:checkbox').on('load change', function() {

  
  
  filter = new RegExp($(":checkbox:checked")
                         .map(function() {
                           return this.value;
                         }).get().join("|") );
  
  $(".box").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this); 
    
    if(filter.test($this.attr("class")) ) {  
        $this.show();  
    }else{
       $this.hide();   
    } 
    if(filter.source == ""){
       $this["show"]; 
    }
  });    
  
   var values = [];
 values[0] = $(".noUi-handle.noUi-handle-lower").attr("aria-valuetext");
 values[1] = $(".noUi-handle.noUi-handle-upper").attr("aria-valuetext"); 
  range_change( values  );  
  
  count_box();  
});

// Range Slider
var range = document.getElementById('range'),
    t = [],
    maximum = parseInt(range.attributes.max.value, 10),
    minimum = parseInt(range.attributes.min.value, 10),
    delta = (maximum - minimum) / 4,
    options = {
      min: [minimum],
      "25%": [minimum + delta * 1, 1e6],
      "50%": [minimum + delta * 2, 1e6],
      "75%": [minimum + delta * 3, 1e6],
      max: [maximum]
    };

//console.log(minimum + delta * 1, 1e6);

t.push(parseInt(range.attributes.min.value, 10)), 
  t.push(parseInt(range.attributes.max.value, 10));
var n = parseInt(range.attributes.max.value, 10); 
// i = parseInt(range.attributes.min.value, 10),

noUiSlider.create(
  range, 
  {
    range: options,
    start: t,
    connect: !0,
    pips: {
      mode: "range",
      density: 2
    }
  }
);

$(".noUi-value-horizontal").each(function() {
  var range = $(this).text().split("").slice(0, -6).join("");
  $(this).html(range);
});

function range_change(values, handle){ 
 $(".box").each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
        price = $this.data('price');
    
    var val1 =  values[0];
    var val2 =  values[1]; 
     
     
    if(price <= val2 && price >= val1 && filter.test($this.attr("class")) ) {
      $this.show();
    }else {
      $this.hide();
    } 
    
  }); 
}
range.noUiSlider.on('change', function(values, handle){ 
 range_change(values, handle); 
 count_box(); 
});

function count_box() {
   countbox = $('.content').find(".box:visible").length; 
   $(".filter-slect").text(countbox);
}

//   var filterSelect = $('.filter-select'),
//     boxs = $('.box'),
//     length = boxs.length;
//     filterSelect.text(length);
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* input[type="checkbox"] {
  display: none;
} */

li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.filter-item {
    border: 4px solid #ccc;
    margin: .1rem;
    padding: .5rem .95rem;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}


input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label,
.filter-item.active, 
.filter-item:hover, 
.filter-item:not(.active):hover {
    background: #333;
    color: #fff;
}

.slider-wrapper {
  margin-top: 1rem;
  margin-bottom: 3rem;
  padding: 0 1rem;
}

.filter-res {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.filter-res span {
  color: red;
}

.box {
  width: 8rem;
  height: 8rem;
  background: #ccc;
  margin: 1rem;
  padding: 3rem 0;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: monospace;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/10.1.0/nouislider.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/noUiSlider/10.1.0/nouislider.min.js"></script>
  
  
<div class="filter">
  Кол-во комнат
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="item">
      <input type="checkbox" id="room-1" value="room-1">
      <label for="room-1" class="filter-item" >
        1        
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <input type="checkbox" id="room-2" value="room-2">
      <label for="room-2" class="filter-item" >
        2        
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <input type="checkbox" id="room-3" value="room-3">
      <label for="room-3" class="filter-item" >
        3        
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <br>
  
  Метраж
  <ul class="list">
    <li class="item">      
      <input type="checkbox" id="area-1" value="area-1">
      <label for="area-1" class="filter-item" >
        50-100        
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="item">
      <input type="checkbox" id="area-2" value="area-2">
      <label for="area-2" class="filter-item" >
        100-200        
      </label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  
  <br>
  
  Цена
  <div class="slider-wrapper">
    <div id="range" max="28420000" min="6130000"></div>
  </div>
  
  <br>
  <div class="filter-res">
    Выбрано <span class="filter-slect">0</span> из <span class="filter-all">0</span> 
  </div>
  
</div>
  
  <div class="content">
    <div class="box room-1 area-1" data-price="6140000">
      room="1" <br> area="70" <br> 6 140 000
    </div>
    
    <div class="box room-2 area-2" data-price="17000000">
      room="2" <br> area="70" <br> 17 000 000
    </div>
    
    <div class="box room-3 area-3" data-price="27000000">
      room="3" <br> area="70" <br> 27 000 000
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: @HamSter обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо огромное!!!